# Removing duplicate/overlapping vectors

Tags: corel-draw

Can Corel Draw remove vectors that overlap.  Vectors that are pretty close to the same size and position or even vectors that duplicate a path.  I am working on a CNC machine using Corel Draw as the design software and duplicate lines are duplicate efforts.

Comment: Usually you cant do this very effectively even in software that have this functionality. As detecting them is a pain. And what is truly overlapping? Rebuild or dont make them in the first place.

Comment: There are tools in Corel that can help reduce overlapping such as creating outlines from the object/shaping menu and welding objects together.  But I get files, sometimes, that are very complex and have many hidden duplicate vectors.  I would have imagined that they would have put some purpose built tool in place to deal with this by now.

Comment: you definitely never want to create outlines when laser cutting it just makes a near duplicate path to laser cut 2 times. CNCs and Lasers arent printers.  Ai has cleanup fuctions for printing.  Anyway its not so easy. When do you decide that a curve that is technically different but really close to the other curve that does not share points with parent curve just close to the curve is a duplicate. Welding and outlining does not help here.

Comment: @joojaa I do this all the time.  Put two object together (overlap) and then create an outline and delete the prior shapes.

Comment: sure but if you have a scene consisting of diseparate lines then outlining does not help. But by all means if your shapes are allways closed and never overlapping then illustrator can clean it for you.